# Show coordinates (or ruler) on my Canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, coordinates

I've built a drawing application for figures (ellipse, rectangle...), and I need a ruler on my canvas view that shows the position of the coordinates, something like this, just to show the user where is he drawing:

http://pe-images.s3.amazonaws.com/photo-effects/color-grid/first-guide.gif

How can I do that on XAML (WPF)? Maybe drawing a rectangle at the top and the left but dont know how to show the position numbers. Thank you!